# Laravel Many To Many Get element that I dont have a relationship with

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In laravel Many to Many relationship like the one in the Laravel Documentation example.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string

roles
    id - integer
    name - string

role_user
    user_id - integer
    role_id - integer
```

In the Users model I have

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

In the Roles model I have

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

How can I get all Role that I don't have a relationship to.

I tried thing like

```
$this->availableRoles = Role::doesntHave('users')->get();
```

But this give me all the Role that no user at all have

Any hint on this.

Comment: So you want to get all g role that not related to current user? for example User 'A' have roles [1,2,3] you want to get all roles exclude [1,2,3]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a `User` instance (I assume that is what `$this` is?), then you can simply filter the relationship:

```
$this->availableRoles = Role::whereDoesntHave('users', function ($subQuery) {
  return $subQuery->where('users.id', $this->id);
})->get();
```

This should return all `Role` elements, unless that Role has an association with the `User` (`$this`, `$user`, `auth()->user()`, etc.; adjust as required).

An alternative approach, filter out Role based on existing Roles:

```
$this->availableRoles = Role::whereNotIn('id', $this->roles->pluck('id'))->get();
```

This approach get's the `roles.id` for the `User` instance.

You can take a look at query efficiency and use the one that works best, but either approach should work fine.

Note: If `$this` is not a `User` instance, adjust:

```php
$user = User::find($userId); // or `auth()->user()`, etc.

$availableRoles = Role::whereDoesntHave('users', function ($subQuery) use ($user) {
  return $subQuery->where('users.id', $user->id);
})->get();

// OR

$availableRoles = Role::whereNotIn('id', $user->roles->pluck('id'))->get();
```

Comment: The first part or your awnser is exactly what I need. I think I tried something similar earlier but I for sure made a mistake in my query. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem! Took me a couple tried to get it correct too; it's an odd query, since it's using an reverse-where `whereDoesntHave()` combined with a `->where()`, but if you break it down a bit, it gets a bit more clear. Cheers!